# Developer Story "Synchronize with your profile" checkbox does not respect profiles where inheritance was disabled

Tags: bug, profile-page, developer-story, stack-exchange, personal-data

I'm talking about this checkbox that appears above certain fields in the Developer Story while editing:

[image: Title Full-Stack Web Developer Where you live Hungary tooltip with checkbox Synchronize with your profile]

I foolishly thought this was somehow going to use values entered in my SO profile as the value of the field in the Developer Story, but what it did instead is upon saving update all fields for which I had this checked across **every single one** of my Stack Exchange site profiles, including ones where I chose not to copy my main profile details to (aka. "Save changes just for this community").

Thanks to this, up until I noticed this change, those other profiles have been publicly displaying a website address which I did not want to associate with said profiles. If I had checked this for my location, I believe the same would have occurred with the value of that field.

I'm not sure how common of a use case it is to have this profile data inheritance turned off in certain communities, but this really caught me off guard. I feel like this should have come with a large warning letting me know that I'm about to plaster this information everywhere, not just be an innocent checkbox with a vague description dangling above the field.